# Airflow - No module named 'airflow.contrib.operators.mssql_to_gcs'

Tags: sql-server, python-import, airflow

I found this operator in GitHub `https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/mssql_to_gcs.py`

but when I try to run, I get this error message:

```
 No module named 'airflow.contrib.operators.mssql_to_gcs'.
```

What do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: @Zack mysql_to_gcs should be under airflow.contrib.operators.*. And based on the error message, Felipe already put that import in his python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MsSqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator was introduced on Apr 22 2019. And it hasn't been released yet. If you want to use it, copy the code and use it as your own plugin.

Reference: 
https://github.com/apache/airflow/commits/master/airflow/contrib/operators/mssql_to_gcs.py